# jQuery selector on a collection

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my code I have the following which gets a collection of the Country radio controls:

```
model.countries = $('input:radio[name="Country)"]');
```

Later in the code I need to know the val() of the "checked" radio. How do I get to it?

I've tried:

```
model.countries.is(':checked')
```

but that of course just finds if any is checked. I need the val() of the checked radio.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`.filter(selector)`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to filter your current selection, then call [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) to retrieve the value of the desired element:

```
model.countries.filter(':checked').val()
```